# null value when trying to display french words (with accent)

Tags: mysql

Hi all when  i try to display this word : `INTERMARCHÉ` from my MySql data base i got null, help please :)
the collation for the corresponding column is `utf8_unicode_ci`

**EDIT**

```
 $nomsDesStations=$this->db->query('SELECT DISTINCT ssiphone_enseigne from ssiphone_recherche where ssiphone_enseigne!="AUTRE"');
  array_push($tousLesNomsDesStations,"");
                 while($enseigneEnCours=$nomsDesStations->fetch()){

                 array_push($tousLesNomsDesStations,$enseigneEnCours['ssiphone_enseigne']);

       }
```

and for display :

```
foreach($tousLesNomsDesStations as $valeur){
         echo $valeur['ssiphone_enseigne']."<br />";
       }
```

Comment: Could you provide a test case or at least the way you are trying to display it? Or any other details?

Comment: Yep, please provide the query and how it's being used.

Comment: please take a look on my edit :)